# What is the probability of selecting at least two aces given deck of 52 cards?

Tags: probability

1. What is the probability of selecting at least two aces given a deck of 52 cards. We are selecting 4 cards randomly and the question is what is the probability of selecting at least 2 aces?
2. ( referring to the same exercise) What is the probability of choosing maximum of 3 clubs?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the selection is without bias and without replacement, given $N$ total objects, $K$ of which are of one type and $N-K$ of which are of the remaining type, the probability of getting exactly $k$ objects of the one type when choosing $n$ objects will be:

$$\dfrac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

This is the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  On the top, we counted the number of possible outcomes where we have $k$ objects selected of the first type and the remaining $n-k$ objects needed to bring the total number of selected objects up to $n$ of the second type and divided by the total number of ways to select $n$ objects.

Now, for your case, you simply use $N=52,K=4,n=4$ and calculate for each of $k=2,3,4$.  For the clubs problem, you instead have $K=13$ and instead have $k$ ranging over $0,1,2,3$.

Answer (score 0):

If the case is with replacement:
use the binomial distribution formula

Answer is $$1-(4C0*(4/52)^0*(48/52)^4+4C1 *(4/52)^1*(48/52)^3)$$

If it is without replacement;

$$((4C2*(4/52)*(3/51)*(48/50)*(47/49))+(4C3*(4/52)*(3/51)*(2/50)*(48/49))+(4C4*(4/52)*(3/51)*(2/50)*(1/49)))$$

Comment: That would be with replacement.  With these deck of cards questions it is heavily implied that we are selecting *without* replacement.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: It is correct now, but I still far prefer having used binomial coefficients to simplify notation here like I have in my answer

Comment: But how could we solve this exercise using basic probability formulas?